# Sharepoint 2007 - cannot discard current draft

Tags: 2007, versioning, draft

Ive been investigating this problem but am yet to find a suitable answer.
We have a draft sharepoint page that someone accidentally deleted a web part from.

The published version is still fine and showing the page correctly but i understand that you cannot delete the most recent draft in the version history.
I thought i may be able to restore the current published version thus making it the latest draft and then publish that again but it seems that the restore option does not extend to the webparts on a page and so the new draft still has the missing webpart.

So my question is, how do i get the most recent version back to being the same as the published version so we can then continue making amendments without losing the webpart?

Comment: Didn't we have discard checkout option in SharePoint 2007 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restore the web part, since it is only reference to webparts in the sharepoint pages, SP page points to null value, only content can be saved in the web part page, Check in two recycle bins at site level and Site collection level to restore the web part.

or Try toupload dummy webpart to restore the page- this is bit tricky and need to be careful with atmost important